# Selected Index Changed event not firing for a DropDownList during databind at pageload

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdownlist (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList) which I Bind during the pageload.

```
try
     {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
           {
              DataTable dt = new StaticNoticeController().GetStaticNoticeNames();
               this.HeadingsDropDownList.AutoPostBack = true;
               this.HeadingsDropDownList.DataSource = new StaticNoticeController().GetStaticNoticeNames();
               this.HeadingsDropDownList.DataTextField = "NoticeName";
               this.HeadingsDropDownList.DataValueField = "NoticeId";                  
                 this.HeadingsDropDownList.DataBind();                                       

           }
     }   
catch (SystemException ex)
    {
                //ToDo: Log the Exception
    }
```

I expect the SelectedIndex event to get fired when I bind the dropdown to a combobox ( which use to happen in case of Comboboxes in Winforms ) so that the page is loaded with values corresponding to the initial value in the dropdown list.

I even tried

this.HeadingsDropDownList.selectedIndex = -1;
in pageload after databind. But in vain .

When I change the index of the dropdown through the browser , the event gets fired as usual.
Am I missing something or am I trying to perform something which is not possible ?

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would essentially mean that when you load the site it would directly postback. It would be stuck in a loop.

If its an inited value, then what the postback would do should be done in the init.

Comment: Thanks..Seems like the solution you suggest will work. But Page init fires even before page load. So if I write the code in Page_LoadComplete , the issue which I face will be fixed.

Comment: Indeed. With init i didnt mean asp.net's init, but your own initialization routines, preferly called in page load.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to fire the SelectedIndexChanged-Event?? As you have already mentioned, the selected index will change if the user changes it manually on client-side. This is the desired behaviour. If you initially want to call a function on serverside that would be also called when the selected index changes, call it manually!

Comment: Thanks. The dropdown has a set of values. Based on the value in the drop down , a grid will be diplayed (This happens in the SelectedIndex Changed event).  If the SelectedIndex Changed event doesnt fire, page opens with values in the dropdown but the grid will be empty.  I need the grid to be filled based on the initial value in the dropdown.